# GameMaker: how to make one non-physical object collide with a fixture?

Tags: platformer, game-maker

I've searched a lot and i couldn't find the answer. I'm developing a platformer game where i need the player to stay on ground but i don't want to use build-in physics to make him move. The ground is a multi-point fixture, since i've read using objects lowers performance. However, if I set the player as non-physical object, he doesn't collide with the ground.[image]

Comment: Just set the player as a physics entity, allowing it to translate but not to rotate

Comment: Write your own physics, look up Shaun Spalding, he has a tutorial on platformers

Comment: I came to the conclusion that i will implement both Box2D and some of the tutorial's. So thank you for your feedback :).

Answer (score -1):

Two ways of doing it, *way1* use GameMakers built in buggy physics (GREAT RIGHT?)... So lets ignore that, skip to *way2* and build your own set of physics for it, you could do this by setting your own physics, something along the lines of the following;

*Code Example*

```
#v_speed =0.5;    
h_speed =0.5;
vsp =v_speed*grav;    
grav = v_speed -1;
//Something like this
vsp = grav*v_speed;
if (vsp<10) vsp +=grav;
```

This is just something quick, youl need to tweek it more for yourself.